# Capybara not working with action_cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm using the Rails 5 beta 3 with action cable, the integration works fine in development but when I try to run a feature test through capybara, it doesn't seem to hit the channel actions.

I'm using Portergeist and configured puma as capybara's server. Also I'm using es5-shim and es6-shim.

Has anyone else experienced this or knows any workaround?

Thanks!

Edit

Im using this capybara branch to configure Puma in Capybara

```
Capybara.register_server :puma do |app, port, host|
  require 'puma'
  Puma::Server.new(app).tap do |s|
    s.add_tcp_listener host, port
  end.run.join
end
```

I have not set anything on config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins

Comment: Please show your configuration of puma as Capybaras server

Comment: Also - what have you set  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins to in your test config

Comment: @TomWalpole I just edited my question. I think I'm using your capybara PR to configure Puma :). Also,   config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins is not set.

Comment: ok -- rather than trying to configure allowed_request_origins in the test env with unknown ports, names, etc I just set `config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true` in my test.rb - which allows connections from any location

Comment: From here: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#allowed-request-originse

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: How are you specifying the connection location for action cable? Are you using action_cable_meta_tag in your layout? Are you hardcoding in your JS?

Comment: I am using action_cable_meta_tag . Also configuring App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer() just like that, without specifying an address. Please note that this configuration works fin in development mode

Comment: One last guess -- Did you specify  Capybara.server = :puma  ??  Without that the server would be registered but Capybara would still start webrick.  If thats not it I would say say it's time to debug the browser connection and see whats happening --  (also I assumed you were using a JS capable driver with capybara - seems too simple but just verifying)

Comment: Yesss that was it! Can you add that response as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For testing actioncable with Capybara you need to be using a multithreaded  webserver.  Since you're using a current pull request on Capybara that supports registering named drivers you will need to specify the named server to use

```
Capybara.server = :puma
```

For anyone not using the capybara branch with named servers you can do

```
Capybara.server {|app, port| 
  require 'puma'
  Puma::Server.new(app).tap do |s|
    s.add_tcp_listener Capybara.server_host, port
  end.run.join
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. Hope your PR gets merged

Comment: As the main developer of Capybara - I'm the one who determines when it gets merged :)  I need to write documentation for it before I merge it

Comment: @SergioMárquez I somehow accidentally down voted your question -- could you edit it slightly so I can remove that vote

Comment: lol, I didn´t realize that! Thanks for your harddd work  then. Capybara is awesome! I eddited my question

Comment: Where should I put this capybara configuration?

Comment: @marcpt Wherever you're configuring Capybara -- usually rails_helper.rb or spec_helper.rb -- -If you're using the Capybara master branch you can just specify `Capybara.server = :puma` now.

Answer (score 6):

From Capybara v2.7.0 passing a block to `Capybara::server` is deprecated ([commit](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/66ec44c457880df0693c5b9b29abd2da9d78c2d1#diff-f6aa6c79750a9a5bd39ee17f3ade2974)).

[Deprecation message](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L177):
`DEPRECATED: Passing a block to Capybara::server is deprecated, please use Capybara::register_server instead`

To register new web server (for example `puma`) use:

```
  Capybara.register_server :puma do |app, port, host|
    require 'puma'
    Puma::Server.new(app).tap do |s|
      s.add_tcp_listener host, port
    end.run.join
  end
```

Link to [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.register_server)

Comment: in v2.7.0, puma is already a registered webserver. Capybara.server = :puma will work just fine.